# Fill down rows in Excel with correct format

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a file that has a data format as such:

```
 date

 10/01/2019
 10/01/2019
```

However, I wish for the format to be:

```
 date

2019-10-01
2019-10-01
```

I realize that I can do 'Fill down', however, there are over 10,000 rows within the dataset.
Is there any command that I can do within excel to accomplish this?

(I have transformed in Python correctly, however, when I save back to .csv, the format returns to 10/01/2019)

```
  df.insert(loc = 0, column = 'Last_Refreshed', value =  '2019-10-01')
```

[image]

Comment: Would only take a couple seconds for Excel to format the way you want (highlight column, right-click, format cells, custom format).But as far as why python to csv is not keeping your desired format, that seems odd. When viewing the csv in an editor such as Notepad++, are you seeing the wrong format there? Maybe it's just excel that is changing the format.

Comment: Ok this works! Thank you. I just researched that Python has a 'date_format' parameter that you must apply in order for this to work